# ALAssets setImageData not overwrite the original Photo

Tags: objective-c, alassetslibrary, alasset

Having problem with setImageData in ALAssets, which it indeed set a new image into the ALAsset, and the user will see it in their Photo Album, but in the actual file system, it just generate a new photo, instead of overwriting the existing Photo.

I notice it when I jailbreak the phone, where DCIM folder on the file system shows that the original photo still there, and was never clean out from the folder, even after restarting or reboot. This also makes the iCloud / Phone backup sync all the original photo with it. At the same time, these photo were never shown to user for some reason. It simply become a dummy data in the folder system.

This behavior persist in both iOS 7 to iOS 8.1 . This is where the "Others" storage space came from for the most part and were never able to find out what that is or delete it.

It seems to be that the API is simply broken on Apple's part, but no one finds problem with it, because no body investigate it before.

Comment: In iOS 8, you can solve this problem by using the Photos framework instead of the Assets library framework.

Comment: Photo framework is not a option, since it always create delta file and required user permission to do anything.

Comment: So we should write different code for different ios versions ?